# Merge two geojson files

Tags: qgis, geojson, merge

I have a global json files about countries' boundaries but the Russia is in two parts (two polygons). I want to merge the two parts in one, without the boundary at the middle.
[image]

Is there a way to "repair" that with QGis?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two options:

1. You could try using this [python script](https://gist.github.com/migurski/3759608), to merge.
2. Add the geojson into QGIS, convert to shapefile, edit/merge features, and finally export back out to geojson.

Comment: Now it's good, I did the merging with qgis like you suggest to. Thank you !